# Could not start the command: /usr/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Roberta".tex

Tags: mactex, macos

After having updated the operative system for mac I get errors as in the title when I attempt to compile tex-documents in Texmaker. Is there something I can do to resolve this problem without calling for a specialist?

Comment: Please tell us which version of MacOS you were using *before* the most recent update. The reason I ask is that your query is vaguely reminescent of postings that occurred about two and a half years ago, around the time of a major update of MacOS.

Comment: @Mico: If I remember correctly, the last version of MacOS X where it was possible to create subdirectories of `\usr` was Yosemite.  In any case, the problem should go away automatically with an update to the latest version of MacTeX: since 2015 (again, IIRC) the MacTeX distribution puts executables (virtually) into `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

Comment: @GuM My latest version of MacTex is from 2016, it appears.

Comment: You have to change from using `/usr/texbin` to `/Library/TeX/texbin` since your updated OS no longer allows the use of the former link.

Comment: @Herb Schulz Your suggestion indeed helped me resolve the problem. Thanks! Perhaps you could write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change from using `/usr/texbin` to `/Library/TeX/texbin` since your updated OS no longer allows the use of the former link.